# How to stream motion jpeg using CGI?

Tags: c++, http, cgi, jpeg

I'm creating an Web application that need to display a video that I'm grabbing from a high speed camera.
For that, I'm trying to create a Motion JPEG CGI application that just outputs these frames as a JPG sequence when the browser access this CGI application.

So my question is: how can I create a simple C++ code that just read a sequence of JPG files and then print it's output in other to be loaded by the browser a JPG sequence?

I have tried the following code, but it is not working...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Cache-Control: no-cache\n\n";
    std::cout << "Cache-Control: private\n\n";
    std::cout << "Pragma: no-cache\n\n";
    std::cout << "Content-type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=spiderman\n\n";

    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        sprintf(buffer, "/tmp/img_%d.jpg", (i%2));
        FILE* fp = fopen(buffer, "r");
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fread(buffer, 1, 1, fp); 
            fwrite(buffer, 1, 1, stdout);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        i++;
        std::cout << "--spiderman\n";
        std::cout << "Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first step to fixing this, is to use either `stdout`, or `std::cout` to generate the output, but not both. And the second step, after deciding which one you will use, is to correctly implement copying more than one byte at a time, between the file and the standard output. That's not going to "stream" very well.

Comment: I'm doing just a test...
So I wish the most simple code, before any optimizations.

Comment: `stdout` versus `std::cout` is not an optimization. Using both, like this, is likely to fail in mysterious ways, since each one has completely independent internal buffers that have absolutely no knowledge, whatsoever, of each other's existence. Random parts of `stdout` will be intermixed with random parts of `std::cout`, in the actual output on file descriptor #1, with hilarious results.

Answer (score 1):

After a very hard binary debugging, I was able to come up with a simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary\r\n\r\n");

    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        char fnameBuffer[1024];
        sprintf(fnameBuffer, "/tmp/img_%d.jpg", (i%2));
        FILE* fp = fopen(fnameBuffer, "r");
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        long fileSize = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);

        char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*fileSize);
        fread(buffer, 1, fileSize, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        free(buffer);

        i++;
        printf("--jpgboundary");
        printf("Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n");
        printf("Content-length: %ld\r\n\r\n", fileSize);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, fileSize, stdout);
        printf("\r\n\r\n\r\n");

        usleep(1000);
    }
}
```

This actually loads a sequence of images and flush them to the browser.
I tested the output with Google Chrome, and it is working as expected.